# Why is 'können' at the end of this sentence? Which structure is used in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

> Die Jugendministerin hat keine Programme für die sinnvolle Freizeitgestaltung der Schüler entwickeln können.

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Do you mean: "Why is the word *können* positioned at the end of the sentence, not elsewhere"? If so, where else would you put it?

Comment: yes, you get me . sorry I can't express myself so clearly

Answer (score 2):

In some **southern German dialects**, people say

> Die Jugendministerin hat keine Programme für die sinnvolle Freizeitgestaltung der Schüler entwickeln **gekonnt**.

The basic structure is

> <Subjekt> hat <Infinitiv> gekonnt.

So, it's *Perfekt* tense of *können*, and this requires an infinitive of the action which someone can do.

There's another complication however. Standard German doesn't like this infinitive+participle construction. Instead, it's infinitive+infinitive.

> <Subjekt> hat <Infinitiv> **können**.

This **Ersatzinfinitiv** applies to all modal verbs (*dürfen*, *können*, *mögen*, *müssen*, *sollen* und *wollen*) and the verbs *brauchen*, *lassen*, *sehen*, and sometimes *hören*, *fühlen*, *helfen*.

Comment: You could even continue this structure by adding more modal verbs: "Die Ministerin hat keine Programme für sinnvolle Freizeitgestaltung der Schüler **entwickeln können sollen**." This is of course not a sentence to be used in standard situations. However, in some satirical comment it could well appear, and would be well-formed there.